# SQL SUM(QTY) but only for records where QTY > 0

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum, case

**Edit:** how would one handle this when there is another criteria (see below, added code) and `qtyRemaining = SUM(qty)` when code IN (25, 26) but NOT 27.

I have a series of records, some where qty < 0, others where qty > 0. I have fields 1 and 2 below, my goal is to get field 3:

```
ref_x         qty     code      qtyRemaining(goal) 
--------------------------------------------------
TKAB030AA      0      25            0
TKAB030AA      0      25            0 
TKAB030AA     -3      26            0
TKAB030AA    -197     26            0
TKAB030AA      3      27          -200
TKAB030AA     197     27          -200
```

The logic is, if `qty < 0`, then `qtyRemaining` should be 0, but if `qty > 0`, `SUM(qty where trcode IN(25, 26))` (even records where `qty < 0`) grouping by `ref_x`.

The problem I'm running into is that I cannot do:

```
CASE 
   WHEN qty < 0 
      THEN 0 
      ELSE SUM(QTY) 
END [QtyRemaining]
```

...because SQL wants me to put qty in a group by since it's outside of the `SUM()` function. but if I do:

```
, SUM(CASE WHEN qty < 0 THEN 0 ELSE QTY END) [QtyRemaining]
```

...this isn't what I want either. Is there some way to do this that I'm just not seeing? Please help!

Comment: where did you get 50?

Comment: What about where `qty = 0`? That's not covered by your cases of `qty < 0` and `qty > 0`.

Comment: 400 + -350 (grouping by ref_x), but only when qty > 0, else 0

Comment: OK, I modified my answer below (slightly) to accommodate the possibility of `qty = 0`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use a window function here. Aggregation is not really what you're after, since you seem from your question to want all rows to show:

```
SELECT ref_x, qty
     , CASE WHEN qty <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(qty) OVER ( PARTITION BY ref_x ) END AS [QtyRemaining]
  FROM mytable;
```

You could get the same answer by using aggregation and joining the table to itself, but that's a lot more typing:

```
WITH t2 AS (
    SELECT ref_x, SUM(qty) AS total_qty
     GROUP BY ref_x
)
SELECT t1.ref_x, t1.qty
     , CASE WHEN t1.qty <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE t2.total_qty END AS [QtyRemaining]
  FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
    ON t1.ref_x = t2.ref_x;
```

**EDIT FOR NEW CONDITION:**

I think you'll want this:

```
SELECT ref_x, qty
     , CASE WHEN qty <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN code IN (25,26) THEN qty ELSE 0 END) OVER ( PARTITION BY ref_x ) END AS [QtyRemaining]
  FROM mytable;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked great, Thanks! I edited my code because I came across a twist that I didn't realize would be there and I don't see a way to add a where clause in the partition.

Comment: Your edit for new condition worked perfectly. Thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from using `cte` like below. Please try:

```
;with cte (ref_x, qtyRemaining) as (
    Select ref_x, sum(qty) as qtyRemaining
    from table
    group by ref_x
)
select t.ref_x, t.qty, (case when t.qty > 0 then cte.qtyRemaining else 0 end)
from table t
inner join cte on t.ref_x = cte.ref_x
```

Comment: I think where you have `cte.qtyRemaining>0` you really want `t.qty >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
select ref_x, qty, sum(qty) over(partition by ref_x) as qtyRemaining
from table;
```

sum(qty) over(partition by ref_x) is what do the trick